# Increasing money when the dealer or player win the game

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner I am trying to add money if I wont to the money that I typed in the very start of the game if I won the money will be added to the input money that I had it adding but repeating its looping example I typed 500 then I won 200 price It will display 700 but if I won again and the price 300 it will show 800 and forgetting about what I won before

below is the code I will really appreciate your hep thank you

```
import random, sys
from random import shuffle
from _ast import Num

# define global variables for the cards

suits = ('Clubs', 'Spades', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds')
pip = ('Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King')
pipValues = {'Ace':11, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '10':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10}

playing = True
global score
score=0

class Card:

    #When you create an instance of Card, you pass it a suit ("C", "D", "H", or "S") and a "pip" (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 J, Q, K, A).
    #These values should be stored as instance variables for the new card object.
    #I recommend you also have an instance variable "value" that stores the point value of the card.
    #It should have an __str__ method that lets you print an individual card (such as "3S" for three of spades).
    #Note that the __str__ method for Decks should take advantage of the __str__ method for Cards.

    def __init__(self, suit, pip):
        self.suit = suit
        self.pip = pip
        self.value = pipValues.get(pip)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pip) + " of " + str(self.suit)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()




class Player:

    #When you create an instance of Player, it should have an instance variable "hand" that's set to an empty list,
        #and an instance variable "handTotal" that's set to zero. These instance variables will be modified
        #by Deck's "dealOne()" method.
    #It should have an __str__ method that lets you print out a Player's hand.



    def __init__(self, isDealer):
        self.hand = []
        self.isDealer = isDealer
        self.name = "Dealer" if self.isDealer else "You"
        self.other = "Dealer" if not self.isDealer else "You"
        self.has = "has" if self.isDealer else "have"

    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join(map(str, self.hand))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def discardHand(self):
        self.hand = []

    @property  
    def handTotal(self):
      while sum(card.value for card in self.hand) > 21 and \
            any(card.pip == 'Ace' and card.value == 11 for card in self.hand):
        for card in self.hand:
          if card.pip == 'Ace' and card.value == 11:
            card.value = 1
            break
      return sum(card.value for card in self.hand)

    def blackjack(self):
        print ("%s %s %s for a total of 21" % 
          (self.name, self.has, str(self)))
        print ("%s %s a Blackjack! %s win%s!" % 
          (self.name, self.has, self.name, "s" if self.isDealer else ""))

        print ("Thanks for playing. Come back again soon! ")
        #chips=chips+(bet*500)
        score+1
        return message()

    def bust(self):
        print ("%s hold%s %s for a total of %s" % 
          (self.name, "s" if self.isDealer else "", str(self), str(self.handTotal)))
        print ("%s Bust%s! %s Win%s!" % 
          (self.name, "s" if self.isDealer else "", self.other, "s" if not self.isDealer else ""))
        print ("Thanks for Playing! Come Back Soon!")
       # chips=chips-2
        return message()



class Deck:

    #When you create an instance of Deck, it should add 52 Card objects to an instance variable "cardList".
    #It should have a shuffle() method that rearranges the cards in cardList. You can do this easily by importing the
        #"random" package into Python, and using the random.shuffle() method. random.shuffle(myList) rearranges the
        #elements of the list "myList" into a random order.
    #It should have a dealOne() method that removes the first card from your deck's cardList, and appends it to the
        #hand of a specified player.
    #It should have an __str__ method that lets you print out the entire deck for debugging purposes.
    freshDeck = []
    for i in range(len(suits)):
            for j in range(len(pip)):
                freshDeck.append(Card(suits[i], pip[j]))


    def __init__(self):
        self.cardList = self.freshDeck[:]

    def shuffle(self):
        random. shuffle (self.cardList)

    def dealOne(self, player):
        if len(self.cardList) < 4:
          print("Out of cards... shuffling a new deck...")
          exit 
          #self.cardList = self.freshDeck[:]
          #self.shuffle()
        (player.hand).append(self.cardList[0])

        del self.cardList[0]
        #print(self.cardList)
        shuffle(self.cardList)
        return self.cardList

    def __str__(self):
        printString = ""
        for i in range(len(self.cardList)):
            if i % 13 == 0:
                printString += "\n \t"
                printString += str(self.cardList[i]) + " "
            else:
                printString += str(self.cardList[i]) + " "
        printString += "\n"

        return printString


def showHands(player, opponent):
    print ('Dealer shows ' + str(opponent.hand[0]) + ' faceup')
    print ('You show ' + str(player))


def turn(deck, player, other):
    #First, check scores to see if either player has a blackjack:

    if player.handTotal == 21:
      return player.blackjack()
    if other.handTotal == 21:
      return other.blackjack()

    #See if the dealer less 16 

    hitOrStand = 0
    while hitOrStand != 2:
        print (player.name + ' hold%s ' % ("s" if player.isDealer else "") + str(player) + ' for a total of ' + str(player.handTotal) + '\n')
        if player.isDealer:
          if player.handTotal < 16:
            hitOrStand = 1
          if player.handTotal >= other.handTotal:
            hitOrStand = 2
        else:
          hitOrStand = input('Do you hit or stand? Enter "1" for hit and "2" for stand: ')
          while hitOrStand != 1 and hitOrStand != 2:
              try:
                  hitOrStand = int(hitOrStand)
                  break
              except ValueError:
                  print ("Enter a valid integer \n")
              hitOrStand = input('Do you hit hit or stand? Enter "1" for hit and "2" for stand: ')
          print()

        if hitOrStand == 1:
            print('Card dealt:  ' + str(deck.cardList[0]) + '\n')
            deck.dealOne(player)

        if player.handTotal == 21:
            return player.blackjack()

        if player.handTotal > 21:
            return player.bust()

        #if player.handTotal <16 :
            #return player.bust()

        if hitOrStand == 2:
          if player.isDealer:
            print ("Dealer stands at " + str(player.handTotal))
            global price
            price=bet*500*2

            print (price )
            print ("Dealer Wins!")
            return message()
          else:
            print (player.name + ' stand at: ' + str(player.handTotal))
            print()
    print ("Now Dealer's Turn\n")

def message():
    global playing
    again = raw_input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ")
    if again.lower() == "n":
        print("\n\n-------Thank you for playing!--------\n\n")
        playing = False
    return True


#who won
def betValidation():
        global number
        number=input("Enter amount: ")

        number
        if (number<5000):
            print "Minimum amount is 5000!!! "
            exit()

        elif (number > 50000):
            print "You Exceeding the Maximum Amount...."
            exit()
        elif (number==5000 , number<=50000):
            if number%500==0:
                print "" 

            else:
                print "Invalid"
                exit()


def main():
    cardDeck = Deck()

    global bet

    bet1=betValidation()

    while playing:
        global chips
        print "Score:",score
        chips=number/500
        print "You have", chips ,"chips!"

        betchips=chips/2
        global bet


        bet=input("How much would you like to bet: ")

        if(bet==0):
            print "Invalid"
        elif (bet>=betchips):
            if bet%1==0:

                player = Player(isDealer=False)
                opponent = Player(isDealer=True)

                player.discardHand()
                opponent.discardHand()
      #give each player 2 cards, alternating
                cardDeck.dealOne(player)
                cardDeck.dealOne(opponent)
                cardDeck.dealOne(player)
                cardDeck.dealOne(opponent)

      #show 1 faceup card for each player
                showHands(player,opponent)

      #start playing
                if turn(cardDeck,player, opponent):
                    continue

                turn(cardDeck, opponent, player)


main()
```

Comment: This code is very hard to read, thus very hard to fix. I recommend you to create more functions, smaller ones (one function for one task). Also, stop using global variables and instead pass in the values to functions as arguments and have the functions return new values.

Comment: thank you for response I'll try your suggestion thank you

Comment: This still isn't all of your code, we don't know what `Player` is for example. I'd suggest you try out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com or http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython instead for problems like this; stackoverflow is more suitable towards shorter problems which can be converted into a [minimum viable product (mvp)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your problem lies in the function blackjack() but you haven't posted that.

Comment: I updated it and posted the code in blackjack thanks a lot for response

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to find where you declare chips (this is the players total amount of "money/chips" right?). It sounds like you are declaring initialising chips everytime you play, resetting it to 500.

Comment: yup looks like everytime the while loop runs you declare chips again (I'm not familiar with python but that's what it looks like to me).

Comment: every 2 chips is equivalent of 1000 if I bet 5000 and I have 10 chips instant convert then if I bet 5 and I won It will be 5*500 to covert it in money and *2 to double it as a price because of being winner but its adding and looping

Comment: I see...thank you  is it okay to creat a function for chips?

Comment: I don't see why not, but try declaring chips outside of your while loop. Like at the top where you declare score.

Comment: I tried but total amount is still looping thank you alot

Comment: chips *500 + number is my total amount